# Doubts on the proof of the definition of the local connection form in Nakahara's book

Tags: differential-geometry, mathematical-physics, fiber-bundles, connections, principal-bundles

I've been reading Nakahara's book on topology and geometry for physicists and got stuck on the proof of definition of the local connection form $\omega $.

So, given a Lie-algebra-valued one form $\mathcal{A}_i$ and a local section $\sigma:U_i\rightarrow\pi^{-1}(U_i)$, there exists a connection one-form $\omega$ such that $\sigma^{*}_i\omega=\mathcal{A}_i$. He states that $\omega$ is a Lie-algebra-valued one-form defined by $$\omega_i=g^{-1}_i\pi^{*}\mathcal{A}_ig_i+g^{-1}_id_pg_i$$, where $d_p$ is the exterior derivative and $g_i$ is the group element appearing in the definition of the canonical local trivialization. So for an $X\in T_pM$ $$\sigma^{*}_i\omega_i(X)=\omega_i(\sigma_{i*}X)=\pi^{*}\mathcal{A}_i(\sigma_{i*}X)+d_pg_i(\sigma_{i*}X)...$$.
and goes on to the end of the proof. My question is about the step above: what happened to $g_i$ and $g^{-1}_i$ in the first term and to $g^{-1}_i$ in the second term? How did they disappear? The second is, since $\mathcal{A}_i$ is defined in the base manifold $M$ and $\sigma_{i*}\in T_{\sigma_i}P$, then how is the object $\mathcal{A}_i(\sigma_{i*}X)$ well defined?

Comment: Is it Sakurai that you're reading or Nakahara? If so can you leave a page reference and I can have a look

Comment: Sorry for the confusion. I'm following Nakahara's book. It is on page 377, Eq. 10.77. I'll edit the post.

Comment: No problem, maybe you'll find your answer in the page following in figure 10.2. $g_i$ here is the identity so that's why we're allowed to drop $g_i$ and its inverse. Secondly in the equation it is $\left(\pi^* \mathcal{A}_i\right)(\sigma_{i * }X)$ which is well defined.

Comment: Thank you. I understand the answer to the second question. But there is something I still don't understand regarding the first one, why can't I drop $g_i$ in the second term? $g_i$ is also equal to e, right? It's because of the exterior derivative?

Comment: He does drop the second term with the exterior derivative since $g_i$ is constant (since its the identity along $\sigma_{i*}X$), finally using that $\pi\circ \sigma_i =\text{Id}$ completes the proof that $\sigma_{i*}\omega =\mathcal{A}_i$